# Update Inner text value of XML node with variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I am having the following XML

```
 <Lists xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <List ListName="Rules" StructureType="1">
    <Items>
      <Item Level="1" />
    </Items>
  </List>
  <List ListName="Reasons" StructureType="1">
    <Items>
      <Item Level="1"> Not interested</Item>
    </Items>
  </List>
</Lists>
```

I want to add value of inner text to `<Item>` as shown below

```
 <Lists xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <List ListName="Rules" StructureType="1">
    <Items>
      <Item Level="1">Rule100</Item>
    </Items>
  </List>
  <List ListName="Reasons" StructureType="1">
    <Items>
      <Item Level="1"> Not interested</Item>
    </Items>
  </List>
</Lists>
```

I have tried the following snippets but its not adding to inner text. Please suggest any other solution.
I tried with delete and insert but it not modifying properly

```
declare @xmlBlob xml
set @xmlBlob=
 <Lists xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <List ListName="Rules" StructureType="1">
        <Items>
          <Item Level="1" />
        </Items>
      </List>
      <List ListName="Reasons" StructureType="1">
        <Items>
          <Item Level="1"> Not interested</Item>
        </Items>
      </List>
    </Lists>  

DECLARE @RuleName AS NVARCHAR(10) = 'Rule100';
    
SET @xmlBlob.modify('replace value of (/Lists/List[@ListName="Rules"]/Items/Item/text())[1] 
                with sql:variable("@RuleName")')
SELECT @xmlBlob
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/lDmx3DeM `insert text{sql:variable("@RuleName")}  into (/Lists/List[@ListName="Rules"]/Items/Item)[1]`